# shorter way for conditionally setting variables

Tags: javascript

```
if (alev == 1) {
        rb1 = apar;
    }
    else if (alev == 2) {
        rb2 = apar;
    }
    else if (alev == 3) {
        rb3 = apar;
    }
    else if (alev == 4) {
        rb4 = apar;
    }
    else {
        rb5 = apar
    };
```

I suppose there is a shorter way to do this.
`alev` is integer and `rb` always ends with that integer.

Comment: Use switch Statement instead of if else.

Comment: @JeesKDenny, `switch` is another way but not a shorter way.

Comment: i saw the answer. Thanks for the response @bonaca

Comment: Assuming the variables are scoped to the window, you *could* do `window['rb' + alev] = apar;`... but that's not necessarily a *good* solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array rb

```
rb[alev] = apar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    rb[i] = apar;
}
```